# Matlab - How can I sort rows for a bar chart without losing row names?

Tags: matlab, sorting, bar-chart

I am analysing double arrays in Matlab to create bar plots. Each row corresponds to a country and has specific values that are compared. The names of the rows are stored in a cell array and implemented in the bar chart by `set(gca,'XTickLabel',{Combined{:,1}})`. This assumes that the order of the rows remains the same during the analysis.

However, in my analysis I need to sort rows to find the best and worst performing countries. By doing this, I cannot plot the bar charts with the countries corresponding to their countries. This is how I sorted the double data:

```
[~,SortLR2018] = sort(d2018(:,4));
LR2018 = d2018(SortLR2018,:);
```

Does anyone know how I can sort the names of the countries (cell arrays) such that they match the sorted values (double arrays)?

Comment: does this `set(gca,'XTickLabel',{Combined{SortLR2018,1}})` work? I think you can use the indices of the sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to index the cell array containing the names with the indices of the sorted data:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{Combined{SortLR2018,1}})
```

I would recommend implementing your data as [tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html?searchHighlight=table&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), which allows you to link the names to to all kinds of row data.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works! I think I made a mistake with selecting column data. I accepted your answer!